# Get the file name from a full or relative path knowing that this one is not a parameter of the batch

Tags: batch-file, filenames

When a file, along with relative path or full path..., is given as a parameter of a batch, I know how to expand %1 to get the file name

```
    %~n1
```

It's quite easy!

Nevertheless, I want to get the name of file from its relative/full path which is right handled inside the batch.

Please look at my code. I'd like to expand %%x (which is a relative path in my case) to take account only its file name. Please do you have any idea?  Thanks

```
 @echo off
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
 set currDir=%CD%
 for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (Lists.out) do (
 echo %%x
 set filetxt=%%x)
```

Here's an example "Lists.out" file with some different files built-in relative paths.   "Lists.out" can be made of

```
   Temp\my file1_X
   Temp\my file2_X
   ...............
```

Comment: Instead of `"tokens=*"` you should use `"delims="`.  Then if you want to expand `%%x` to a full drive:path\filename.ext use `%%~fx`.  See the last couple of pages of `help for` for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
 echo %%~nx
 set filetxt=%%~nx)
```

should cure your problem.

or use `~nxx` if you want the extension too.