# How to Extract the file name from a full path in bat?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

A variable `%result%` contains the path `"D:\My Folder1\My Folder 2\My Folder 3\The Important File.txt"` . I want to store `The Important File` in some another variable. That is, I want to extract the file name (Without extention) from a full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you need.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("%result%") do set "newvariable=%%~na"
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a solution here: [Get the file name from a full or relative path knowing that this one is not a parameter of the batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071783/get-the-file-name-from-a-full-or-relative-path-knowing-that-this-one-is-not-a-pa?rq=1)

here: [Get filename from string-path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393248/get-filename-from-string-path)

here: [In Batch: Read only the filename from a variable with path and filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454670/in-batch-read-only-the-filename-from-a-variable-with-path-and-filename?rq=1)

Please search existing questions before creating duplicates.

Comment: This will include the extension of the file.

Comment: remove the `%~x` to truncate the extension.

Comment: Thank you both. Next time I will try to improve my search keywords.